# Setup JMX exporting in Wildfly 15 domain configuration with JDK11

Tags: jmx, java-11, jmx-exporter, wildfly-15

I'm trying to setup JMX exporting to plug in Prometheus metrics. Wildfly 15 with Java 11 is used. In domain config I have such a block:

```
<jvm-options>
                    <option value="-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,org.jboss.logmanager"/>
                    <option value="-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"/>
                    <option value="-Xbootclasspath/a:/opt/wildfly/wildfly-15.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.1.5.Final.jar:/opt/wildfly/wildfly-15.0.1.Final/jboss-modules.jar:/opt/wildfly/wildfly-15.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/slf4j/impl/main/slf4j-jboss-logmanager-1.0.3.GA.jar:/opt/wildfly/wildfly-15.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/wildfly/common/main/wildfly-common-1.4.0.Final.jar"/>
                    <option value="-javaagent:/opt/wildfly/wildfly-15.0.1.Final/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.1.jar=58080:/opt/wildfly/wildfly-15.0.1.Final/jmx_prometheus.yml"/>
                </jvm-options>
```

This setup works fine with Java8, a similar setup works fine in Wildfly 10.
But the Wildfly15+Java11 bundle results in such an error:

```
[Server:wf01] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The LogManager was not properly installed (you must set the "java.util.logging.manager" system property to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager")
```

Tried various workarounds found all over the Internet but to no avail. Any clues?